# Android Application in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

I have tried creating different AVDs but each of them pops up with this message.

[image]

Comment: I think you should create emulator based on x86 architecture

Comment: ya @AlexSlipknot i created using intel atom x86 but it throws error that intel haxm is not installed.in android SDK manager also it shows that it can't be installed on Windows

Comment: In order to use Haxm you need to set it in the BIOS. See here for a full explanation for how to do it and what to do: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html

Comment: Also I would recommend you to use real device because android emulator is critically slow.